# Asked to set PIN for credential storage

Tags: storage

I've never had a smart phone before. Now, I'm being asked if I want to set a pin or pasword for my "credential storage" before using it. I'm not even sure what this is. It looks like I do not have much storage left and I've had this phone only a few months.

Answer (score 1):

It's for installing VPN and SSL client authentication certificates that you use to access VPNs or web servers that use certificates as logon credentials. It's fairly rare to need to use credential storage for the majority of Droid users. If you don't possess any digital certificates that identify you,it has no value to you.(found in some forum)